# CSS property that grows on both the direction from center of parent element till it reaches end of screen

Tags: html, css

```css
.rightDiv {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 350px;
  }
  
  .content{
   width:50%; 
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    top:10px;
  }
  
  #spandiv {
    display: block;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color: #232F34;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity:1;
    top:5px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
  
<body>
  <div class="rightDiv">
    <input type="text"/>
    <div class="content">
        <p id="spandiv">10122019(tjwmxuwmiihcxdfryfgfhrunlfsxrkhvmyqjjuwjddknjaybnrobpzferxaenxzenbkmlqqzesvfbnnsxwydfbzgbaxkccvoplgjxbikxjifojjmvqxmbjbrtmvbngq)</p>
      </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to CSS, I want CSS style property that grows the text in both the direction from center of parent element till it reaches end of the screen. I am not familiar with CSS properties, If such a property doesn't exist at all, can I create my own custom style ( I am stuck in my project I want to UI to look as I shown in the description below)

[image]

Comment: Can you please your code in the snippet?

Comment: I have inserted code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code you have ask like this

Demo

```css
        .mainDiv {
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .content {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 10px;
        }
        
        .content p {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 18px;
            background-color: #232F34;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            padding: 15px 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <title>StackOver flow</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <input type="text" />
        <div class="content">
            <p>10122019(tjwmxuwmiihcxdfryfgfhrunlfsxrkhvmyqjjuwjddknjaybnrobpzferxaenxzenbkmlqqzesvfbnnsxwydfbzgbaxkccvoplgjxbikxjifojjmvqxmbjbrtmvbngq)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird request, but follow this; you should create a parent with a ceratin `width` and `height` and make the child `absolute` and give it `left: 0` `right: 0` to center it inside the parent:

```css
#parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 4px solid;
    margin: auto;
}

#child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>

  <div id="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pedram :) , I don't want child element to be inside parent but below the parent, just that it grows in length on both the ends till it reaches end of screen. Upon reaching the end, remaining text should appear in next line

Comment: @karansys Check updated answer, is this what you want?